# Неправильно определяется формат файла в Sublime text 3

Tags: html, linux, css3, linux-mint, sublime-text-3

При открытии файла с форматом html, в редакторе sublime text 3, открытый файл неправильно определяется. Файл определяется как css 3, как указано на скриншотах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить? 
P.S.
Использую операционную систему Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вручную выбрать тип файла, нажав на тип здесь: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень странный баг, возможно поможет переустановка Sublime. Или попробуйте создать еще один файл и открыть

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена: помогло переназначение синтаксиса по умолчанию для всех .html файлов